# How to write a working timer for animation?

Tags: javascript

There is an input where I have to set the animation time in seconds. There is a button that starts this animation. But here's how to make the animation work until the specified time ends?

```js
const moveUp = () => {
    const anm = document.querySelector('.animation');
    let position = 0;
    let setPosUp = 350;
    let add = 1;
    let up = setInterval(moveUp, 1);

    function moveUp() {
        if (position == setPosUp) {
            setPosUp = 0;
            add = -1;
            //clearInterval(up);
        }
        else {
            position = position + add;
            anm.style.bottom = `${position}px`;
        }
    }
}

const up = document.getElementById('up');

up.addEventListener('click', moveUp);

let myTime;
let timer = document.getElementById('timer');
let countSeconds;
function startTime() {
    myTime = setInterval(start, 1000);
    document.getElementById('timerr').innerHTML = timer.value;
    countSeconds = timer.value;
}

function start() {
    countSeconds--;
    document.getElementById("timerr").innerHTML = countSeconds;
    if (countSeconds == -1) {
        stop();
        document.getElementById("timerr").innerHTML = "0";
    }
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(myTime);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #b8f9f4;
}

.animation {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: crimson;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

button {
    display: flex;
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.ball {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.fa-solid {
    font-size: 60px;
}

.btn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.stop {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.fa-hand {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="animation"></div>
        </div>
        <input id="timer" type="number" value="0">
        <p id="timerr"> 00 </p>
    </div>
<div class="ball">
        <button id="up" class="btn fa-solid fa-caret-up" onclick="startTime()">
        </button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn stop" onclick="stop()"><i class="fa-solid fa-hand">Stop</i></button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The Stop button should stop the animation wherever it is and store it in localStorage. I'm just learning Javascript.

Comment: [May be of use](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-play-and-pause-css-animations-with-css-custom-properties/).

Comment: @BenAston - Thank you! I will definitely read it, because I have no knowledge yet keyframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The much easier way to do this, and also far more performant way, is to use CSS animations, not JS.

To do this, create a new keyframe animation and apply it to a class. You can then add this class to your target element when you want the movement to start.  You can dynamically control how long the animation will take by setting the `animation-duration` value.

Also, I'd strongly suggest you review how you name your variables and functions. Give them all meaningful names, and absolutely do not define a new function with the same name as the outer function.

In addition, be consistent with how you retrieve elements from the DOM, ie. stick with `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` or `getElementByX`, not both, and also be consistent with how you define functions, either use function expressions or function declarations, not both.

Here's a working example with all the above applied to it:

```js
const animationLength = document.querySelector('#timer');
const countdown = document.querySelector('#timerr');
const up = document.querySelector('#up');
const animation = document.querySelector('.animation');
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
let countdownInterval;

const startAnimation = () => {
  if (animation.classList.contains('move'))
    return;

  animation.style.animationDuration = animationLength.value + 's';
  animation.classList.add('move');
  startCountdown();
}

const startCountdown = () => {
  countdownInterval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
  document.getElementById('timerr').innerHTML = timer.value;
  countSeconds = timer.value;
}

const updateCountdown = () => {
  countdown.innerHTML = --countSeconds;
  if (countSeconds <= 0) {
    stopAnimation();
  }
}

const stopAnimation = () => {
  clearInterval(countdownInterval);
  countdown.innerHTML = "0";
  animation.classList.remove('move');
}

up.addEventListener('click', startAnimation);
stop.addEventListener('click', stopAnimation);
animation.addEventListener('animationend', stopAnimation);
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #b8f9f4;
}

.animation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: crimson;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation-duration: 0;
}

.animation.move {
  animation-name: move_up_return;
}

@keyframes move_up_return {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 350px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

button {
  display: flex;
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.ball {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-solid {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.stop {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fa-hand {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="animation"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="timer" type="number" value="0">
  <p id="timerr"> 00 </p>
</div>
<div class="ball">
  <button id="up" class="btn fa-solid fa-caret-up"></button>
</div>
<button class="btn stop"><i class="fa-solid fa-hand">Stop</i></button>
```

Comment: thank you very much! Due to lack of knowledge keyframes, I could not write like that and thought that everything could be written in javascript. I listened to your advice and will try very hard to use it!